# Is this proof of L'Hospital's rule correct?

Tags: calculus

Assume $f(a)=g(a)=0$, $f'(a)$ and $g'(a)$ exists, and $g'(x)$ is not zero in some neighborhood of $a$.

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} &= \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)} \\
&= \lim_{x\to a}\frac{(f(x)-f(a))/(x-a)}{(g(x)-g(a))/(x-a)} \\
&= \frac{\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-f(a))/(x-a)}{\lim_{x\to a}(g(x)-g(a))/(x-a)} \\
&= \frac{f'(a)}{g'(a)}
\end{align*}
$$

Most proofs I've seen are based on Rolle's theorem. I am not sure if this 'simpler' proof works or not.

Comment: It works if $\,g(x)\neq0\,$ in some neighborhood of $a$ and if $\,g’(a)\ne0\,.$

Comment: You do not need differentiabilty of $g$ for $x\neq a.$ If $g'(a)\neq 0$ then the last denominator is nonzero for $x$ close to $a.$ The conclusion of the general Hospital rule is $\lim_{x\to a}{f'(x)\over g''(x)}.$ This time the differentiability close to $a$ is required and that $g'(x)$ is nonzero close to $a.$ But differentiability at $a$ is not required. In many examples it  is essential.

Comment: @Angelo If $g'(a)\neq 0$ then $g(x)\neq 0$ for $x$ close to $a, $ $x\neq a.$